VBA find and replace data in a table when a duplicate is found
I have a following problem with my code. Im trying to write a macro that does the following steps:
1)User types in name in B21 and number in E21 in a Sheet WADY
2)After pressing the button it moves name and number to a table in a sheet DATA WADY (in column B we have a name and in C we have the number)
3)when a duplicate is found in column B then it overwrites the number in column C
4)when no duplicate is found then it adds a new row at the end
Sub ZGLOS()
Dim data As Worksheet
Set data = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA WADY")
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim Srch As Range

LastRow = data.Range("B1048576").End(xlUp).Row

name = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WADY").Range("B21").Value
number = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WADY").Range("E21").Value
Set Srch = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WADY").Range("B21")
For r = 2 To LastRow
Set y = Srch.Find(data.Cells(r, "B").Value, , xlValues, xlWhole, xlByRows, xlNext, False, False, False)
If Not y Is Nothing Then
data.Cells(r, "C") = number
Else
data.Cells(LastRow + 1, "B") = name
data.Cells(LastRow + 1, "C") = number
End If
Next r

End Sub

Steps 1,2,4 are working fine but I have a problem with step 3 - it does overwrite the number in existing duplicates but it also additionally adds a new row with the same name and number and I can't seem to find where the problem is.

You have lots of variables that you haven't defined: Name, Number, r, and y.  You might benefit from adding Option Explicit to the start of your code, and/or going "Tools" → "Options", and checking the "Require Variable Declaration" box.  Furthermore: "Name" is a reserved variable if you run this code from a Worksheet (rather than a Module), which controls the name of the Sheet.  Something like strName would be safer…

Suppose for a moment that the first few rows of Columns B and C of "DATA WADY" sheet look like this:



Name
Number




Alan
1


Ada
2


Charles
3



And in the "WADY" sheet you put the Name "Alan", and the Number 4
LastRow is 4, so we loop from r=2 to r=4, which looks like this:

r=2
data.cells(2,"B") = "Alan", so y=data.Cells(2,"B")
y is not Nothing, so data.Cells(2,"C") is changed to 4


r=3
data.cells(3,"B") = "Ada", so y=Nothing
y is Nothing, so you add a new entry on row LastRow+1 (i.e. Row 5)


r=4
data.cells(4,"B") = "Charles", so y=Nothing
y is Nothing, so you add a new entry on row LastRow+1 (i.e. Row 5)
(This overwrites the row already created for Ada)

And then the loop ends.
The issue would have been more apparent if you dynamically-calculated the insertion row every loop, rather than locking it at LastRow+1, e.g.
    With data.Cells(data.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)
        .Offset(1, 0).Value = Name
        .Offset(1, 1).Value = Number
    End With

would have created a new entry for each non-"Alan" entry (i.e. two new rows, one for "Ada" and one for "Charles")
So, you want to try to do this without a loop:
Sub ZGLOS()
    Dim data As Worksheet
    Set data = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA WADY")
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim toSearch As Range, outResult As Range
    
    LastRow = data.Cells(data.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim strName As String, lngNumber As Long
    strName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WADY").Range("B21").Value
    lngNumber = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WADY").Range("E21").Value
    
    Set toSearch = data.Columns(2) 'Column B of Data
    
    'Search the Data Column for the Input Value, not the other way around!
    Set outResult = toSearch.Find(strName, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    
    If outResult Is Nothing Then 'Name does not exist in Data
        data.Cells(LastRow + 1, "B") = strName
        data.Cells(LastRow + 1, "C") = lngNumber
    Else 'Name already exists in Data
        outResult.Offset(0, 1).Value = lngNumber
    End If
End Sub


As an alternative, you can use the below code where ADO and SQL used. Code is prepared and tested on Excel 2010 64 Bit.
I assumed that your sheet "DATA WADY" is something like below;
Check the column labels with your orginal sheet and adjust in the code if necessary.
.



Name
ID NO




Name1
100


Name2
101


Name3
102


Name4
103


Name5
104


Name6
105


Name7
106


Name8
107


Name9
108


Name10
918


Name11
110


Name12
1000


Name13
112


Name14
113


Name15
254



Sub Test()
    Dim adoCN As Object, TargetFile As String, strSQL As String, RS As Object
    Dim myName As String, myNumber As Long
    
    myName = Sheets("WADY").Range("B21")
    myNumber = Sheets("WADY").Range("E21")
    
    Set adoCN = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    
    TargetFile = ThisWorkbook.FullName
    
    adoCN.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    adoCN.Properties("Data Source") = TargetFile
    adoCN.Properties("Extended Properties") = "Excel 12.0; HDR=Yes"
    adoCN.Open
        
    strSQL = "Select Count([Name]) From [DATA WADY$] Where [Name]='" & myName & "'"
    
    Set RS = adoCN.Execute(strSQL)
    
    If RS(0) > 0 Then
        strSQL = "Update [DATA WADY$] Set [ID NO] = " & myNumber & " Where [Name]= '" & myName & "'"
    Else
        strSQL = "Insert Into [DATA WADY$] ([Name], [ID NO]) Values('" & myName & "', " & myNumber & ")"
    End If
    
    adoCN.Execute strSQL
    
    adoCN.Close
    Set adoCN = Nothing
    Set RS = Nothing
End Sub

